# How to use a position in a list in an if statement?

Tags: list, if-statement, filter, position

I am trying to make a program that will remove certain numbers from a list, for example to remove every 3rd number. I was thinking I could do this by using an if statement for if the position mod 3 = 0 then remove that number? I'm unsure on how to get the position to be able to use it like this?

I attempted to use this code:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,]
print(list)

j = list[j]
if (j-1) %3 == 0:
  list.remove[j]
  print(list)
```

It only outputs error messages as j is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any need for an If statement since the index of the 3rd number in any list will be '2' we can just delete that using the del function. I think the reason it shows that the error code telling you that j is not defined is because j is not an index number and is not present in the list, so you can't just tell it to delete j. The code below should work.

```py
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(list)
del(list[2])  # this will delete any number in the 3rd position
print(list)
```